# pause and resume on flashloan

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

Is it possible to pause a initiated flashloan and resume after some parameter met.

I read on solidity docs, all function are require some sort of user action to execute.

Just incase I miss out if there any method to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

A flashloan needs to be repaid in the same transaction in which it was initiated. If it's not repaid, the whole transaction reverts as if it never happened (however the transaction sender still pays the gas fees).

So it is not really possible to pause and resume a flash loan, as it either happens all in one instance - or it doesn't.

The user action is usually executing one contract, that performs several internal calls within the same transaction:

1. initiate the flash loan
2. perform some kind of trade with the loaned funds
3. give aproval to the flash loan contract to pull the funds back
4. repay the flash loan

Comment: In that case, possible to pro long the trade function (i.e 1-5 minutes) after initiate the flashloan?

Comment: @cklai If it spans through more than one transaction, then it's not a flashloan in the original meaning, but some other type of (possibly short term) loan. For flash loans you don't need a colateral - you borrrow 10k USDT for example and repay back 10.1k USDT in the same transaction (where the 0.1k is the fee for taking the loan)... While for these other types of crypto loans, you usually need to provide some colateral. For example you send them 10 ETH with the total value of 15k USDT, borrow 10k USDT, and when you repay the loan back (plus interest), they release the 10 ETH back to you.